# SonarQube showing some issues with Technical debt as "blank"

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-4.5

I'm using SonarQube 4.5.4 to run analysis on my JAVA project and then loading the results into SonarQube. SonarQube is showing the issues, but for few issues technical debt is blank.
When I pullout reports using Sonar webservice api I get issues with blank debt for certain rules

Following are 2 sample rules for which debt is "blank", these below rules are part of findbugs plugin:

**findsecbugs:XXE_DOCUMENT  The usage of DocumentBuilder.parse(...) is vulnerable to XML External Entity attacks**

**checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.imports.ImportControlCheck  Missing an import control file.**

Is technical debt not defined for all rules in findbugs plugin ruleset?

Answer (score 1):

You've correctly diagnosed the problem: not all rules have technical debt definitions.

SonarQube Findbugs Plugin v3.3 was released on 1 Sept 15 and the description includes "Fix missing SQALE debt", so it may be what you want.

From the commit comments of the SonarQube Checkstyle Plugin, v2.3 includes an update to the SQALE model, but there's no guarantee that update included all the rules.

OTOH, technical debt definitions should be in place for all the SonarQube Java Plugin rules. :-)

Comment: Thanks Ann for the quick reply. Is there any evidence or official source which documents this? I need this as my client team is waiting for the issue report to be fixed, so I want some proof before I tell them about this.

Comment: Check the release notes for those versions.